# Errors with Propel commands in Symfony 1

Tags: java, php, symfony1, propel

I work on a project developed with Symfony 1.2 and I can’t use the following propel commands without generating errors :

```
propel:build-schema, propel:build-model, propel:build-forms.
```

I use:

- Apache 2.4
- PHP 5.4.27
- Propel as ORM
- SfPropelPlugin

When executing the commands “`php symfony propel:build-schema`” and “`php symfony propel:build-model`”, I receive this error message :

```
PHP Strict Standards:  Declaration of Win32FileSystem::compare() should be compatible with FileSystem::compare($f1, $f2) in D:\vmd\application\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\plugins\sfPropelPlugin\lib\vendor\phing\system\io\Win32FileSystem.php on line 475
```

When executing the command “`php symfony propel:build-forms`”, I receive this message (but the forms could be generated) :

```
PHP Warning:  ob_start(): function '' not found or invalid function name in D:\vmd\application\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\config\sfApplicationConfiguration.class.php on line 157
```

I looked on the forums, but I found nothing working, as this person before me :
http://forum.symfony-project.org/forum/22/topic/87601.html

#### Problem with Java 8 ?

I wonder if my problem hasn’t come after I upgraded to Java 8 ...
I have now the jre1.8.0_71 version.

#### Upgrading to Symfony 1.3 and 1.4 :

I tried to upgrade to Symfony 1.3 and 1.4 and I installed SfPropelORMPlugin, but I had other problems, even more important because I could even not access the homepage of the website, for instance.

Can anybody help me ?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/issues/387 ?

Comment: Yes, I looked at this post, but unfortunately, I couldn't apply the solution to my problem, because I haven't found any composer.json file in my application folder to upgrade phing.

Comment: I think I will give up for the moment, as it may not be blocking, except that the generated schema is not conformed to the database entries, which is the most important problem (for instance, if I modifiy a field in the database, the schema doesn't take into account this change) ...  Thank you for your support.

Comment: Unless you were using Tomcat for Windows, Java has nothing to do with this issue. [According to the Phing bug report](https://www.phing.info/trac/ticket/752), it seems like you definitely have to upgrade Phing. Worse case scenario, download it from Phing's site and try manually upgrading it?

Comment: I have found a part of the issue to fix the warning "ob_start()" here : http://blog.adin.pro/2013-02-28/warning-ob_start-function-not-found-or-invalid-function-name-symfony/

Answer (score 0):

I think the command should be:
symfony propel-build-model
symfony propel-build-schema (given you have correct propel.ini)
symfony cc (to clear cache dont forget this command)